# cant python3 pip package I just uploaded? ("Could not find a version that satisfies..")

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pypi

I made a pip package and uploaded it here:

https://pypi.org/project/audacityDiscogsExporter/0.1.0/

If i run `pip install audacityDiscogsExporter==0.1.0` or `pip install audacityDiscogsExporter` I get an error saying :

```
martin@MSI:/mnt/c/Users/marti/Documents/projects/package$ pip install audacityDiscogsExporter
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement audacityDiscogsExporter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for audacityDiscogsExporter
```

Why can't I install this package?

Comment: Use `pip3` to install your package.

Comment: `pip3` is a shortcut that might work or might as well be as wrong as just `pip`. It doesn't clearly alleviate the uncertainty that is the cause of the issue. I would not recommend that advice without further explanations.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to use a Python 2 interpreter to install a Python-3-only project.

When using `pip` (or actually any other Python script directly), it is important to make sure which Python interpreter is used. Usually it is obvious which Python interpreter is used when calling `pip`, but it also often happens that it is not clear. It is better to call the exact Python interpreter explicitly always. Typically:

```
$ python -m pip install Something
$ # instead of 'pip install Something'
$ python3 -m pip install Something
$ # instead of 'pip3 install Something'
```

If there is still doubt, one could even go one step further and use the full path to the Python interpreter explicitly:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3.8 -m pip install Something
$ /path/to/myvenv/bin/python3 -m pip install Something
```

An interesting read on the topic: [Brett Cannon's article "Why you should use `python -m pip`"](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/)

Comment: @Martin Does that answer your question? Need any further clarification?